# Parsing Variable into TCPDF

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

my problem is : undefined variable test.
My Code :

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

extract ($datapr);

$test = $datapr ['ref_no']; //print_r $test will be = 'PR/1.2.3.4/OK'

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

   public function Footer() {
      $test;
   }

}

?>
```

Problem is undefined variable for $test inside function footer. Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try with in side function

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

   // Or  rename Footer to index();
   public function Footer() {

      extract($datapr);

      // print_r $test will be = 'PR/1.2.3.4/OK'

      $test = $datapr['ref_no'];

      echo $test;
   }

}
```

If this is a controller then only the first letter of class name should be upper case `My_pdf.php` and `class My_pdf extends TCPDF {}`

Comment: if I put it inside the function, the $datapr will be return NULL

Comment: putting the 'extractor' inside footer function worked, footer might be getting call before rest of